# Exception won't be caught if I don't debug the application

Tags: c#, debugging, exception

There are two DLLs, A and B, in A.DLL there is a form class like this:

```
namespace AAA
public class AForm: Form
{
  ...
  private void btnOK_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
  {
      DoSomeSth();
  }
}
```

In B.DLL, there is some code like this

```
try
{
   AForm dlg = new AAA.AForm();
   dlg.ShowDialog();    
}
catch(Exception ex)
{
   MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
}
```

There will be exception in the function **DoSomeSth** after OK button is clicked
When I debug the code using vs2005, the exception could be caught in B.DLL, but if I ran the application directly without debug, the exception won't be caught in B.DLL, what is the reason?

Comment: Where is the exception thrown? Where is the code for that? There isn't enough information in the question for an answer.

Comment: Good question, I can reproduce this.

Comment: By debug, you mean u attach a debugger, or the code is compiled in debug mode, rather than release?

Comment: @Theofanis Pantelides: debug in the VS debugger, yes.

Comment: @zespri Debug>Exceptions>Reset All; and try exception again. And we'll take it from there.

Comment: @Theofanis Pantelides: please read my answer. This turned out to be a known issue. Nothing to do with VS settings.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a [known issue](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/836674). According to the KB article:

> When you run your Windows Forms
>   application without using the
>   debugger, you use the
>   **NativeWindow.CallBack** method to catch
>   the exception and to prevent the
>   program from unexpectedly quitting
>   (crashing). In the
>   **NativeWindow.CallBack** method, you
>   populate the exception message by
>   using a standard exception dialog box.
>
> However, if you run your Windows Forms
>   application with the debugger, you do
>   not catch the exception because you
>   use the
>   **NativeWindow.DebuggableCallBack**
>   method. When you use the
>   **NativeWindow.DebuggableCallBack**
>   method, the just-in-time (JIT)
>   debugger stops the application from
>   running.